# How to attach tracking code to anchored link for an email newsletter while retaining scroll to view?

Tags: analytics, html-email, event-tracking

I'm trying to figure out how to attach a tracking code to a link and still keep the anchor functional. This will be used in an email newsletter.

ex:

`www.example.com/welcome#Intro` so that link would scroll down to the intro section right?

now if I were to do the same thing but like this `www.example.com/welcome#Intro?TrackingCode` the scroll no longer works.

I tried to google it but I couldn't find anything, any suggestions?

thanks for your time!

Comment: Don't think you can track scrolls. The images load top to bottom. We can't use anything like lazy load as JavaScripts don't work in emails unless it's viewed in the browser. If you want to use on browser then you can use jQuery to do that.

Comment: oh I see, thank you Syfer! I thought that might be the case but wasn't sure.
Could you post that as the answer so I can mark this resolved. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can track scrolls. The images load top to bottom. We can't use anything like lazy load as JavaScripts don't work in emails unless it's viewed in the browser. If you want to use on browser then you can use jQuery to do that.